# Why does the cut property of the real numbers require $ A \cup B = \mathbb{R} $ ??

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

The cut property states that, if A and B are nonempty disjoint sets with $ A \cup B = \mathbb{R} $ and a < b $ \forall a \in A $, $ \forall b \in B $ then $ \exists c \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $ \forall a \in A $,  $ a \leq c $ and $ \forall b \in B $,  $ b \geq c $

my question is why does $ A \cup B $ has to be equal to $ \mathbb{R} $ ?? When  I prove the cut property from the axiom of completeness or vice versa I don't need to use the property $ A \cup B = \mathbb{R} $.

Comment: In some cases where $A \cup B \not = \mathbb{R}$ then the $c$ may not be unique

Comment: in fact it is not necessary, but I guess it is in the definition of "cut property"

Comment: Is the uniqueness necessary ? does defining it this way have any benefit ? (makes certain theorems easier to prove without proving another lemma/corollary)